# Finding Ruby on Rails logfiles in Google's App Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I deployed my rails app to google app engine. How can i check or where do i find the logfiles generated by rails? Usually they are located in [appname]/log/production.log

Thanks & regards, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/writing-application-logs). To quote from the docs related to Ruby:

> App Engine automatically sends these logs to the Cloud Logging agent, and you can view them in the Logs Viewer, on the command line, or programmatically.

Edit: This applies both to GAE [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/writing-application-logs) and Flexible (previous link).